# Fill textfield with JavaScript

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery

I have a textfield which needs to get the value of a variable.
When I select the `<input>` by it's ID, and use  `jQuery.val(variable)` I get [] as output (Chrome Developer Tools).

When I use JavaScript `.value = variable`, I get the value of the variable as output, but the field isn't changing in neither of these cases.

Comment: The `[]` output is most likely the jQuery object representing all your elements - in your case no elements, which explains why nothing happens (your selector is wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you have a jQuery library referenced.

Then this should work:

Set value - `$("#id").val("Hello World");`

Get value - `$("#id").val();`

You should be able to see it happen instantly using Developer Tools.

Comment: That's what I tried...

Comment: In that case I would agree with eirikb and that your selector is incorrect.  Try something like `$("input[id='id']").val();` to see if that works.